# Stream Android Emulator Display on Website

Tags: java, android, html

I want to develop a website where client can view the actual emulator working at a remote site.

User uploads his/her APK file to install in remote emulator (running somewhere).

My question is how can I stream a remote emulator display on browser?

Without installing any third party app on emulator device, such as TeamViewer or something that resemble the first.

Comment: May be as a video (highly compressed video).

Comment: Consider without installing third party app on emulator device such as TeamViewer etc.